# OpenCV creating a matrix of certain size has the wrong height - C++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix of dimensions that are the max of both dimensions from two existing images. My code is below:

```
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    (frameOne.cols >= frameTwo.cols) ? width = frameOne.cols : width = frameTwo.cols;
    (frameOne.rows >= frameTwo.rows) ? height = frameOne.rows : height = frameTwo.rows;

    cout << "frameone: " << frameOne.cols << " " << frameTwo.rows << endl;
    cout << "frametwo: " << frameTwo.cols << " " << frameTwo.rows << endl;
    cout << "Width: " << width << endl;
    cout << "Height: " << height << endl;
```

The issue that I am having is that when I print out the rows of each frame they are all 711 (as they should be) but the resulting width is 720.. I should just be 711 and do not know where it is getting changed as it is a simple assignment.

Comment: Are you sure the row of each frame is 711? Because at the first cout you are printing `frameTwo.rows` instead of `frameOne.rows`.

Comment: Seems a little complicated - the readability isn't as good as just using max(). Like `width = max(frameOne.cols, frameTwo.cols);`

Comment: Well that is what happens when you stare at it all day, you miss things like that. Thanks a lot that was the issue thus there actually was not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Was printing our the wrong value for the row of frameOne.